# How to send POSIX signal from nodejs

Tags: node.js, signals, posix, send

I just searched a lot and couldn't find a way  to send POSIX signal from nodejs.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i was not able to send a signal directly from simple node js
so i use shelljs to call the shell comamand kill to send my signal

as follows 
`require('shelljs/global');

exec('kill -16 12345')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was not able to send a signal directly from simple node js so i use shelljs to call the shell comamand kill to send my signal as follows

```
require('shelljs/global'); 
exec('kill -16 12345')
```